# Update table rows where not contains string - Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have some code with brings this result ($objeto):

```
QG221999027BR
QG162857207BR
QG189038625BR
NX275612673BR
OP541730334BR
QG145096797BR
QG175292469BR
NX275130092BR
QG253425807BR
QG261617344BR
NX235532760BR
NX235402504BR
NX274705515BR
QG261498063BR
QG187202430BR
QG254884353BR
NX248443459BR
QG158174351BR
NX281519757BR
NX283037908BR
NX274504346BR
QF999161266BR
QG262090602BR
QG190715902BR
QG250416253BR
PM778240144BR
QG128898467BR
OP884100245BR
OP767450527BR
OP548228586BR
OP856065137BR
QG339868665BR
```

The result come from the Select, and now I want to Update all rows in my table which dont have thoose results like "objeto", but always when I run the table all the rows are edited... could someone helps me?

This is my code:

```
$resultado = 'sucesso';
    $rastreador = 'sistema';
    $alerta     = 'sim';
    
    $seleciona_sistema_entregue = $conn->prepare("SELECT t1.* FROM rastreamentos2 t1 JOIN ( SELECT objeto, MAX(id) id FROM rastreamentos t2 WHERE resultado =? AND rastreador=? AND alerta =? AND deletado IS NULL GROUP BY 1 ) t3 USING (id, objeto) ORDER BY id");
    $seleciona_sistema_entregue->bind_param("sss", $resultado,$rastreador,$alerta);
    $seleciona_sistema_entregue->execute();
    $resultado = $seleciona_sistema_entregue->get_result();
    
    while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        $objeto = $row['objeto'];
        
        echo($objeto."<br>");
        
        $verificado = '1';
        $rastreador = 'usuario';
        
        $atualiza_rastreamento_verificado = $conn->prepare("UPDATE rastreamentos2 SET verificado=? WHERE objeto!=? and rastreador=?");
        $atualiza_rastreamento_verificado->bind_param('dss', $verificado, $objeto, $rastreador);
        $atualiza_rastreamento_verificado->execute() or die("erro ao tentar atualizar cliente");
        
    }
```

This is my Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `rastreamentos2` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `objeto` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `rastreador` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_rastreamento` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `hora_rastreamento` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `alerta` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `resultado` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `eventos` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `entregue` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `deletado` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `verificado` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(25) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

With some rows like this:

```
(1, 'NX297269487BR', 'usuario', 0, '03/08/2021', '12:57:02', 'nao', 'objeto nao encontrado', 0, 'nao', NULL, 1, '138.59.31.32'),
(2, 'NX297269487BR', 'usuario', 0, '03/08/2021', '12:57:31', 'nao', 'objeto nao encontrado', 0, 'nao', NULL, 1, '138.59.31.32'),
(3, 'QB479775730BR', 'usuario', 0, '03/08/2021', '14:01:04', 'nao', 'sucesso', 4, 'nao', NULL, 1, '189.121.200.142'),
(4, 'OM454517111BR', 'usuario', 0, '03/08/2021', '14:59:30', 'nao', 'sucesso', 5, 'nao', NULL, 1, '45.232.89.87'),
(5, 'QB557663601BR', 'usuario', 0, '03/08/2021', '17:23:00', 'nao', 'sucesso', 6, 'sim', NULL, 1, '179.209.140.7'),
(6, 'QG221999027BR', 'usuario', 31, '04/08/2021', '16:11:42', 'sim', 'sucesso', 2, 'nao', NULL, 1, '179.218.40.228')
```

Actually have 700 rows, could someone explain to me why my code updates all the rows and not only with the condition !='$objeto' ?

Comment: Hi, your `$objeto` is an external array? Can you please be more specefic from where are you retrieving the `QG221999027BR QG1628572..............`

Comment: Hey @Ruben thanks for your time. The $objeto are the values QG221999027BR QG1628572.............. and I am retriving using the Select in the code.

Comment: Where is your condition in the code?, is really complex to works with conditions in the mysql query, i've not a clear idea of what you want, sorry, more feedback about it is appreciated

Comment: No problem I am sorry for not explain better, here is the condition for UPDATE - SET verificado=? WHERE >>objeto!=?<< and rastreador=?" I am trying to update all rows with not contains the objeto value which I have binded below bind_param('dss', $verificado, $objeto, $rastreador);

Comment: So, explained, you want to update the row that don't match with your `$objeto` array and then put some value from it on the row????

Comment: Yea, I want to update all the rows with verificado='1' where objeto!='$objeto'

Comment: Hey your answer gone, I dont know why but I have copied before, but when tested doesn't worked =/

Comment: yea, deleted because was wrong, let me finish another. i'm trying and it updating me successfully but i need to know the order of the display.

Comment: Can you please show how is your current output of your query?? `$seleciona_sistema_entregue` show as table print if is possible

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you need, Actually the result of my update is set all rows with verificado='1' not only the rows with doens't content $objeto like what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The result come from the Select, and now I want to Update all rows in my table which dont have thoose results like "objeto"

```
UPDATE rastreamentos2
LEFT JOIN ( your query which returns shown `objeto` values list ) t USING (objeto)
SET rastreamentos2.column = new_value
WHERE t.objeto IS NULL;
```

I.e. you do not need to obtain `objeto` values array into your PHP code and iterate over it (SELECT is excess, you may update the table immediately).

---

> but always when I run the table all the rows are edited...

Of course. This is an error in your logic. You check one-by-one for non-presence.

Imagine that you have 2 separate values which must be used for non-presence checking. You check first. All rows except one with current value are updated. Then you check another value. The row not updated on the 1st step will be updated. As a result - any row in a table is updated just now.

Comment: Hey @Akina thanks for your time, dam I got lost now hahah, so your code is the only one? I dont need to do the select first? sorry for the answer.

Comment: @User_349234 if you do not need in shown values list for another purposes - of course you do not need in separate SELECT.

Comment: Yea I dont need to show, only to update the row which have my first SELECT result, but your code is much PRO for me, I got lost where I need to put, sorry I am not too good with MySql.

Comment: @User_349234 I cannot help you in this point, I do not use PHP. Sorry. I think that you must prepare shown query text, bind parameters to it (if needed), execute it, and, maybe, check that it was executed without errors.

Comment: Clicked, sorry for this I doesn't know.